# is it possible to use an normal usb for web authentication (webauthn / fido2)

Tags: websecurity, webauthn

i want to know if it is possible to make a security key out of a normal usb.
i am using webauthn api for php at the moment on a windows 10 device, if you take a quick look at the [demo](https://webauthn.io/) of webauthn and try to register with an usb it wont recognize it as an security key. is there any way to fix this?

i tried using windows aplications like usbRaptor but those will only lock my pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what "a normal USB" actually means, but you need a purpose-built FIDO security key for FIDO2/WebAuthn.

There are many vendors including SoloKeys, HID, Yubikey, TrustKey, and many others. https://fidoalliance.org/certification/fido-certified-products/

Comment: with an normal usb i meant a flash drive you normally use to store data.

Comment: but this answered my question thank you for responding!